# How can I provide a variable for `AWS::RDS::DBInstance` in cloudformation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am using cloudformation to provision RDS aurora to AWS and using `AWS::RDS::DBCluster` and `AWS::RDS::DBInstance` resources in the template. I have different environments, e.g. `dev`, `uat` and `prod`. Each environment has different number of db instances under the cluster. How can I set the number of db instances as a variable in the cloudformation template?

Below is my template for `AWS::RDS::DBInstance`. As you can see there are three instances in the template. It is only for production not dev. How can I use a parameter to indicate the number of instances? For example, deploy 1 instance in `dev` and 3 for `prod`.

```
AuroraDBFirstInstance:
    Type: AWS::RDS::DBInstance
    Properties:
      DBInstanceClass: ${self:provider.postgresqlInstanceClass}
      Engine: aurora-postgresql
      EngineVersion: ${self:provider.postgresqlEngineVersion}
      DBClusterIdentifier: !Ref AuroraDBCluster
      PubliclyAccessible: ${self:provider.publiclyAccessible}

AuroraDBSecondInstance:
    Type: AWS::RDS::DBInstance
    Properties:
      DBInstanceClass: ${self:provider.postgresqlInstanceClass}
      Engine: aurora-postgresql
      EngineVersion: ${self:provider.postgresqlEngineVersion}
      DBClusterIdentifier: !Ref AuroraDBCluster
      PubliclyAccessible: ${self:provider.publiclyAccessible}

AuroraDBThirdInstance:
    Type: AWS::RDS::DBInstance
    Properties:
      DBInstanceClass: ${self:provider.postgresqlInstanceClass}
      Engine: aurora-postgresql
      EngineVersion: ${self:provider.postgresqlEngineVersion}
      DBClusterIdentifier: !Ref AuroraDBCluster
      PubliclyAccessible: ${self:provider.publiclyAccessible}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add it as a parameter and pass as you run the stack, you can even make a mappings like this:

```
Environment:
    Type: String
    AllowedValues:
      - dev
      - uat
      - prod
Mappings:
  EnvironmentToDb
    dev: 
      Cluster: 1
    uat: 
      Cluster: 2
    prod: 
      Cluster: 3
```

Then you can reference it using:
`DBClusterIdentifier: !FindInMap [EnvironmentToDb, !Ref 'Environment', Cluster]`

Comment: Thanks for response. I know I can add parameter. The question is how to control the number of instances in the template.

Comment: That cannot be done with simple CF templates, you might want to use something like Jenkins or Terraform